# how can i pass a url from a variable into frame tag

Tags: php, frame

I have a php page where i have built an url now i want to pass that url into frame tag

```
 <frameset rows="100%">

<frame src=" <?= $url> ?>" />

</frameset>
```

The redirection doesnt seem to happen. Any pointers on what is going wrong?

Thanks

Prady

Comment: What's that stray > doing there after $url?

Comment: You should *always* use [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) on the url (unless of course you have already done this earlier in PHP). Don't know if this would cause a problem in this particular case.

Comment: check that short tags are enabled

Comment: @Andreas Carlbom you were right.. it was the stray >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andreas was right in pointing out the extra > after the url